# Do objects illuminated by the Light cantrip have to stay within a certain distance of the caster to remain lit?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light, cantrips

Is the *[light](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/light)* cantrip limited by distance?

Can you or another player cast *light* on an arrow/bolt, then shoot that at, say, a tree to cast light on an area a bit further away?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.Stackexchange! We have a lot of game system and edition here. Light spell is available on DnD at least 3.5e to 5e, and I believe Pathfinder too. Can you tell us what system you use?

Comment: D&D 5E  light spell, but really 
I'm asking from a point of view from any light spell cast. so in general the same mechanics would still apply. could you cast it on a arrow and then shoot the arrow out and have it land i a tree and give on light to see in a area farther away from you.

Comment: Related: [What happens to lighting when an object the Light cantrip is cast on is broken or destroyed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112297/what-happens-to-lighting-when-an-object-the-light-cantrip-is-cast-on-is-broken-o), [What is the advantage of casting the Light cantrip on an object an enemy is wearing or holding?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49138/what-is-the-advantage-of-casting-the-light-cantrip-on-an-object-an-enemy-is-wear)

Answer (score 6):

## No, there's no limit to how far an object with *light* cast on it can be from the caster.

The description of the [*light*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/light) cantrip says:

> You touch one object that is no larger than 10 feet in any dimension. Until the spell ends, the object sheds bright light in a 20-foot radius and dim light for an additional 20 feet. The light can be colored as you like. Completely covering the object with something opaque blocks the light. The spell ends if you cast it again or dismiss it as an action.
>
> If you target an object held or worn by a hostile creature, that creature must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw to avoid the spell.

The *light* cantrip has a range of "Touch" and a duration of 1 hour. It does not have a range from you within which it works; the lit object simply stays lit until the spell ends.

If you cast *light* on an arrow and then shoot it, the light will not go out as soon as you let go of the arrow; once you cast the spell, the light remains on the object until the spell ends (whether you recast the spell, you simply dismiss it as an action, or an hour has passed). In your example, you could shoot the arrow anywhere you want, and the arrow would stay lit as long as it remained intact and the spell was active.